# iPod Touch 2nd Gen with a dead battery will not reinstall OS

Tags: itunes, battery, ipod-touch, ipod

#### Background

I have an old Ipod Touch 2nd generation 8GB A1288. The battery died some years ago, but I've been using it perfectly, attached to either speakers dock or a usb cable or a powerbank (all of which provide the power for it run perfectly.) Battery is totally zero. If detached from the usb without power, it doesn't even turn on.

Recently I decided to completely reinstall the OS (thinking I'd refresh all the bloatware etc gathered over the years.) Big mistake :(

#### What I've tried

While still attached to the power, I chose the full factory reset option under iOS > settings. The device did some stuff for a while, then it rebooted into recovery mode and threw me a *Connect to ITunes* logo screen.

So I attach the cable to a PC (I don't have a Mac) which has iTunes. iTunes says there's an iPod detected which needs resetting, proceed? I say OK. iTunes goes into the process, downloads etc then installs OS and takes a few minutes. After which iPod restarts, but then again goes to Recovery mode and 'connect to iTunes' logo screen... while on the PC screen, iTunes shows error "could not be restored error 1611". Every time (I've done dozens of times, trying with different good cables, and on different PCs.)

I then tried various 3rd party tools like 3uTools etc. They all detect iPod, ask me to enter Recovery Mode or DFU mode etc (All I did) and they install it but upon a reboot, they all fail because iPod boots again into the Recovery Mode again.

After trying many times, I suspect iPod needs a good battery to reinstall OS. Because when it first reboots after installing the OS, it fails to do or detect something which requires a battery?

By the way, 3uTools has an option where I can see what songs or apps are in iPod, and it shows the list as if everything is still all there! Apparently just the OS is not there for some reason.

#### Question

Is there anything else I can try without having to install a new battery (which I don't have any experience of and I might break the device.) I am hoping for a software only solution here.

Comment: Well, I wish you luck ;) btw, a new [battery](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/iPod/iPod-touch-2nd-Gen-Battery/IF140-000?o=1) is only 15 bucks, but the kit needed will at least double that & the [instructions](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPod+Touch+2nd+Generation+Battery+Replacement/1131) look like an exercise in frustration. I'd be tempted to just find something similar from a junk shop, that at least switches on.

Comment: Thank you for the wishes. :) I have indeed looked at getting batteries, and the horrifying methods of installing them (where folks mostly say they've broken the device, soldered it wrong, or even if they did it right to the book, ipod won't recognize the battery.) May be some wiz here can give more options for me to play (I have alternatives, but I want to revive this one for sentimental reasons.)

Comment: Sure thing. I still have an iPod Photo from '04 that still actually works, so long as you don't leave it unplugged for more than about 18 seconds ;))